# Genetic Algorithms - what makes an algorithm genetic?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I just started studying Genetic Algorithms and without looking at any existing GA in code, I wrote this simple program whose objective is to  guess a number from a given range and that guessed number should match correctly with the expected number. I understand that GA basically evolves until it reaches its expected state.

What this program does is, it generates a random number, compares it with the correct number and adjusts its range after every failed guess and over a period of time it guesses the number correctly as the range gets narrower. Will this program be called a Genetic algorithm?

```
number_to_be_guessed = 10

attempt = 0
start = 0
end = 100
while True:
    guessed_number = random.randint(start,end)
    if guessed_number == number_to_be_guessed:
        print("Number found, which is {}".format(guessed_number))
        break
    elif guessed_number > number_to_be_guessed:
        end = guessed_number
    else:
        start = guessed_number   
    print("Attempt:{} -- Guessed Number:{} -- Start Value:{} -- End Value:{}"\
      .format(attempt,guessed_number,start,end))
    attempt += 1
```

Output

Attempt:0 -- Guessed Number:0 -- Start Value:0 -- End Value:100

Attempt:1 -- Guessed Number:27 -- Start Value:0 -- End Value:27

Attempt:2 -- Guessed Number:22 -- Start Value:0 -- End Value:22

Attempt:3 -- Guessed Number:15 -- Start Value:0 -- End Value:15

Attempt:4 -- Guessed Number:2 -- Start Value:2 -- End Value:15

Attempt:5 -- Guessed Number:6 -- Start Value:6 -- End Value:15

Attempt:6 -- Guessed Number:8 -- Start Value:8 -- End Value:15

Attempt:7 -- Guessed Number:9 -- Start Value:9 -- End Value:15

Attempt:8 -- Guessed Number:14 -- Start Value:9 -- End Value:14

Attempt:9 -- Guessed Number:12 -- Start Value:9 -- End Value:12

Attempt:10 -- Guessed Number:12 -- Start Value:9 -- End Value:12

Number found, which is 10

Comment: your approach is just called "half splitting" and its a common design pattern for troubleshooting or just zeroing in on an answer

Comment: for starters you genes ... essentially some storage of information which is parsed to "grow" some structure ... then you need ability to mutate the genes ... then you need to expose our grown structure to some selective pressure where only the successful structures genes are reproduced and spread ...  read up on notion of DNA , RNA , messenger RNA, protein synthesis, dogma of biology,  and read some good books on molecular biology

Comment: Excellent, I guess thats the best way to understand the analogy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a good summary.](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-genetic-algorithms-including-example-code-e396e98d8bf3)

I don't believe your solution can be called a genetic algorithm.

There are a few things that genetic algorithms tend to have:

There is a representation that facilitates "mutation".  For example, if you can represent the state of your algorithm with a bit-word, and random permutations of the bit-word create valid altered states of your algorithm, then that resembles what you might see in a genetic algorithm.

The representation might also facilitate cross-breeding.  So, using the bit-word example, if you can take half the bits from one solution and half from another and combine them; and that combination represents a valid state of the algorithm, then that resembles what you might see with a genetic algorithm.

Such algorithms tend to survive by natural selection.  So you generally have a fitness function which determines how well you solution works.   Solutions that are poor might be dropped.  Solutions that are good might be mutated or cross-bred for the next iteration of testing.

Your algorithm does not do any of this.

Comment: My initial thoughts were as long as your algorithm evolves under a conducive environment even though cross-over and mutation are absent, its a genetic algorithm. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to know to make a genetic/evolutionary algorithms

1. Define the problem
2. You have to know what do you want to get
3. Then you can start with developing Genetic algorithm

The code you posted is only brute force where you randomly take a number in a loop.

The real GA has some of the following steps:

1. Initialization of first generation
2. Evaluation of this generation
3. Selection of the parents
4. Genetic operations (mutations and crossover) (making children)
5. Evaluation of children
6. Taking some of them as a parents
7. Looping till your fitness function tells that your result is good enough

And there you have it. It is very hard to explain everything here. You will find it everywhere around the internet :)